# Suppose $f(0)=f(n),n\in\mathbb{N}$. Find $f(x)=f(y)$ where $|x-y|\in \mathbb{Z}_+$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Suppose $f$ is a continuous function satisfying $f(0)=f(n)$, where $n$ is a positive integer.

Prove that there exists at least $n$ different solutions $(x,y)$ s.t. $f(x)=f(y)$ and $|x-y|\in \mathbb{Z}_+$.

*My attempt*

From the consideration of some basic situations , I thought the problem may be solved by considering the situation $|x-y|=k$ and $|x-y|=n-k$ together.

I aimed to prove that there exists at least two solutions s.t. $|x-y|=k$ or $|x-y|=n-k$, where $k$ is a positive integer and $k<\frac{n}{2}$.

If $f(k)f(n-k)\ge0$ this can be true, because the continuous functions $g(x)=f(x+k)-f(x)$ and $h(x)=f(x+n-k)-f(x)$ will satisfy that $g(0)g(n-k)\le0$ and $h(0)h(k)\le0$, which leads to they both have at least one zero point.

But I failed to prove that when $f(k)f(n-k)<0$

Any hints? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is that $f(0)=f(n)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ or some $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @Jbag1212 For some $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Consider the function $f(x)$ and $f(x+m)$ where $m \in \mathbb{Z}_+$, $m \leq n$. Must $f(x)$ and $f(x+m)$ intersect?

Comment: @Jbag1212 Sorry, I forget to say $x,y\in [0,n]$

Comment: That condition should be satisfied though. Letting $y=x+m$, then $y-x=m \leq n$ so $x,y \in [0,n].$

Comment: @Jbag1212 Then consider the function $\sin(\frac{2\pi }{n}x)$ when $m＞\frac{n}{2}$

Comment: Let $f(x)$ be a function such that $f(0) = f(n)$ for some positive integer $n$.

Let $m$ be an arbitrary integer such that $1 \leq m \leq n.$ Then set the set of all such $m$'s has size $n$. Let $f(x+m)$ be such that $m$ is as previously described. 

I claim that for any $m$ there exists an $x$ such that $f(x) = f(x+m)$.

Comment: @Jbag1212 what about $n=3$, $m=2$ and $f$ defined piecewise as $f(x)=x$ for $x \in [0,1]$, $f(x)=3-2x$ for $x \in [1,2]$ and $f(x)=x-3$ for $x \in [2,3]$. More simply $f$ is piecewise linear and defined by $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=1$, $f(2)=-1$, $f(3)=0$. Then I claim that $f(x)$ and $f(x+2)$ don't have the same sign and cannot both be zero. As Zero pointed out above, it can be that there are no $x \in [0,n]$ s.t. $f(x)=f(x+m)$...

Comment: @Jbag1212 Yeah, I understand what you said. But just like the example $n=4$ and $f(x)=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}x)$, I think we can't find a solution for $f(x)=f(x+3)$.

Comment: For that particular example $x=3/2$ is a solution.

Comment: @Jbag1212 then $y=x+3 \not\in [0,4]$

Comment: Ah! Is it the case that for each solution $|x-y|$ must be a distinct integer? That is what I was thinking the statement of the problem was - which as your example shows is clearly not true.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that my idea is viable.

We aim to prove that there exists at least two solutions s.t. $|x-y|=k$ or $|x-y|=n-k$, where $k$ is a positive integer and $k<\frac{n}{2}$,
from which we can easily solve the original problem. In order to prove this claim , we only need to prove that 
$$
g(x)=
\begin{cases} 
    f(x+k)-f(x),  & \mbox{if }  x \in [0,n-k]  \\
    f(x+k-n)-f(x), & \mbox{if }  x \in (n-k,n] 
    \end{cases}
$$
 has two zero points where $k$ is a positive integer and $k<\frac{n}{2}$.

Let $a_m \equiv mk $ (mod $n$) and $0\le a_m < n$ for all $m \in \mathbb{N}$. Note that $g(a_k)=f(a_{k+1})-f(a_k) $.
Then using the condition $f(0)=f(n)=0$ we can get $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}g(a_k)=0 $. 
Considering that $g(0)=g(n)=f(k)=f(a_1)$, we can easily arrive at the claim that $g(x)$ has two zero points.

Comment: There is a small but I think correctable problem: As written, for even $n$ we have 2 solutions per $k=1,\ldots,{n\over2}-1$, that means $n-2$ in total; for odd $n$ that becomes 2 solutions per $k=1,\ldots,{n-1 \over 2}$, that means $n-1$ in total. In both cases we can add the solution $x=0, y=n$, which leaves us with one more needed solution for even $n$. But then your constructed $g(x)$ for $k={n \over 2}$ gives this solution: As proved $g(x)$ has 2 zeros at least, they just lead to the same solution as $k=n-k$ in this case.